# Sort table in 2 ways in MS Access

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access

I have made 15 data entries of AFL Players, and I am trying to make a query that sorts them in 2 ways at the same time. At first, I want to sort the 5 team names in ascending order (which I did) and then, for each of the three names in that team, I want them to be sorted in ascending, as in:

```
      Person A,  Adelaide Crows
      Person H,  Adelaide Crows
      Person Z,  Adelaide Crows

      Person B,  Richmond Tigers
      Person Y,  Richmond Tigers

      ... and so on
```

---

So that, the names overall are not sorted together, but only each team's players are sorted, as in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Person,
    Team
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    Team,
    Person
```